# Save Tuple Containing Polygon Coordinates to Shapefile Using Geopandas

Tags: pandas, tuples, shapefile, geopandas, shapely

I'm having trouble converting a tuple containing the coordinates of polygon vertices to a shapefile.

Tuples are a very unfamiliar format to me; if it were in a dataframe, I could do it easily with geopandas.

```
shape= ({'type': 'Polygon',
  'coordinates': [[(-148.7285301097261, 60.42704276401832),
    (-148.7285301097261, 60.42693172262919),
    (-148.7285856304207, 60.42693172262919),
    (-148.72830802694787, 60.42704276401832),
    (-148.7285301097261, 60.42704276401832)]]},
 1.0)
```

I can't convert to dataframe via `pd.DataFrame(shape)`; can't subset the tuple to access coordinates via `shape['coordinates']` or `pd.DataFrame(list(shape))`. I've reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700626/how-to-convert-tuple-of-tuples-to-pandas-dataframe-in-python/33700770), and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301251/geopandas-import-csv-make-polygons-from-x-y-coordinates-based-on-id), but am stuck on getting the coordinates out of the Tuple structure!

How can I create a shapefile (via Geopandas), given a tuple of the structure shown here?

Comment: I may be wrong, but it seems to me you are asking too many things at the same time. 1) [How to access an item in a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136059/getting-one-value-from-a-python-tuple); 2) [How to convert GeoJSON to a GeoPandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45552955/7851470); and 3) [How to write a GeoPandas dataframe to a shapefile](http://geopandas.org/io.html?highlight=shapefile#writing-spatial-data). I'm voting to close this question as "needing more focus".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to convert it to `pandas DataFrame` by reading the first element of the tuple:

```py
pd.DataFrame(shape[0]).explode('coordinates')

Out[1]: 
      type                               coordinates
0  Polygon   (-148.7285301097261, 60.42704276401832)
0  Polygon   (-148.7285301097261, 60.42693172262919)
0  Polygon   (-148.7285856304207, 60.42693172262919)
0  Polygon  (-148.72830802694787, 60.42704276401832)
0  Polygon   (-148.7285301097261, 60.42704276401832)
```

If you need to split into `x` and `y` you can just take the items from the series:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(shape[0]).explode('coordinates').reset_index(drop=True)

df = df.join(df['coordinates'].apply(pd.Series)).rename(columns={0:'x', 1:'y'}).drop('coordinates', axis=1)

Out[2]: 
      type           x          y
0  Polygon -148.728530  60.427043
1  Polygon -148.728530  60.426932
2  Polygon -148.728586  60.426932
3  Polygon -148.728308  60.427043
4  Polygon -148.728530  60.427043
```